# How to create an interface that infers the correct type contextually

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, generics, backend

So below i have an example of what I'd like to do. I want to be able to initialize an empy list of the DbTransactInput and push objects onto the array.

I tried messing with mapped types to get the "Items" in the "Put" property to correctly infer the data type (not looking for a union type) but anything I tried with generics was impossible to instantiate with an empty list and have it dynamically infer after the fact.

```
export interface DbTransactWriteInput {
  Delete?: {
    TableName: keyof DbTableData;
  };
  Put?: {
    TableName: keyof DbTableData;
    Item: DbTableData[keyof DbTableData];
  };
  Update?: {
    TableName: keyof DbTableData;
  };
}

export async function transactWrite(
  input: DbTransactWriteInput[]
): Promise<void> {
  await db.transactWrite({ TransactItems: input }).promise();
}

interface ITableAData {
    test1: "A",
    a: "tableA",
}

interface ITableBData {
    test2: "B",
    b: "tableB"
}

interface ITableCData {
    test3: "C",
    c: "tableC"
}

export interface DbTableData {
  "TableA": ITableAData;
  "TableB": ITableBData;
  "TableC": ITableCData;
}

const transactList: DbTransactWriteInput[] = []
transactList.push({
    Put: {
        TableName: "TableA",
        Item: { // How to get Item to infer type ITableAData given TableName of "TableA"?
            test1: "A",
            a: "tableA"
        }
    }
})
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQIAiARgCozYoDOecA6jEugJIoQCuiA3sAkSABsQ6APwAuBDz59S2YkIBy2ALYgJAaxABPKJiJk5QwtjjYA3LwQBfC3wAKncZMszDIJao3bd+2fJDGprbSzOjKEiR+RibYANqaOnqRboHYALrBNpYAqhAAJiYgTlLSUe4qaggJPsn+qZkWVsCgkLCI2FRaKLgImOzdcEhQKAhwFNS0DEwgABSWqBxwEWTjNLj0jCxsnLFpwACUEnYwUMpIVCAAPABuUEh5AHzOfNgA7thMCHnEAHRjlGsNtMZlwEOQAbRQiBlFQJAtONZ9j8ICczhcZvtGs1UOgsHgCMwygBBVLPaToKhwACMEgARETaQAaFwIbB00z+BnMprAHEYHD4BCEtwAIVJJT4FLgACY6SKmSziOzRbTgDy+XjBcL-ABhcUsqUAZjpOoV0gQuGVutVPPA0HgyDQ-PxvhSMTJtOJtIk2qEJJiwU9Kp9ZTFAcsQetIbcevDPNww0po1WtAAMuclr4U+spltFrsEABeBC7YD-CbrdOU5HsKgACxBLIcmYl5rBbg8lUjfrNbb4UPCkgQAHphwgABJQV6jKAIADmwiFYRnjswGFGWggBOJpLnSGuIBGZU7CB83ZADJELL7kpAlJpCHpvZv0jZj45Pev0ia5qaVn2QA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapped type to generate possible values for `Put`:

```
export interface DbTransactWriteInput {
  Delete?: {
    TableName: keyof DbTableData;
  };
  Put?: PossiblePuts<DbTableData>
  Update?: {
    TableName: keyof DbTableData;
  };
}

type PossiblePuts<Data> = {
  [K in keyof Data]: {
    TableName: K;
    Item: Data[K];
  }
}[keyof Data];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=53&ssc=3&pln=44&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEQCMAVKTJAZxxgHUoFUBJJMAV3gG8AoOA4AG2CoA-AC443Xr2KZCggHKYAtsHEBrYAE8I6AiVmD8mGJgDcPOAF9zvAArsxcWxAoUEc4PZgUAPERkeRiYAfBYAqmAAJsbAjpJSAQrKqnAa2rr+BsBBZhbWXJZcXDCaYHjOru6CXr45wXAAvBIWANoA0ohIqVo6BMaYALri8dJZiiribTZSjKhK4jntA9OFli1pvTnLRcioGDh4jInAAII5zVJwqBQwAIziAEQnDwA0FryYjyYez2+FXLs0FhcHAjlkAELnEZXYA3ABMj3Br3ecEIXwhDwKOxQQIOoOOAGEoSjrjAAMyPAnIy7YdEeKlYrigSCwTp7YF4TKBfoXOAPY7PcRgn45ab8jFC46Q-piwkPSVZIkyxklMp6UjkKjYWj0JgsdgAGQQN0acBOUDImj8JDIlGodAYwGYbBg9QAZLy2BQABYACkwUAA5uIkKwlIQ0ABKENhiNQcz-bAQSjwGC2rUwI03BY2zX23VO-WZ43wJotAZFNN57VZmAAOi9fuhXmGKMux3GKXFP2plxmc2GcAA9EO4AAJCAAdyuEDggaEoLmM866DQV1KhwF50DCAAbsAuh3knBet3BM9hG2+7xSfc+b8r9fPnzvufMdfeIVLqtI0A)

Comment: only thing I noticed with this type is that it will default to a random TableData. So if I start populating `TableName: "TableA"` it says that it isn't assignable to `ITableDataC`, but if you complete the `Item` property as well, with the correct keys, then it correctly infers `ITableDataA`. Is there anyway to avoid this type of initial inference?